# How does Android MediaPlayer Prepare() actually work?

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, http-streaming

I created an app in which I am using Android's `mediaplayer` to stream multiple video files from a HTTP source. I am using the `Prepare()` method instead of `prepareAsync()` since I can't continue unless something is being shown.

Here I have a simple method that return each of the `mediaplayer` instances:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPreparation(String filename) {
    String url = "myURL"; // your URL here
    // create mediaplayer instance
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    // mediaPlayer.start();
    return mediaPlayer;
}
```

And then I start them one by one using `start()`. Now I have two questions:

1- How does `Prepare()` really work? It takes a while for my app to start. Isn't it supposed to first receive a **portion** of the video stream (not download the whole) and then start playing?!

2- Can I manually buffer the video so I have more control over the buffer, and feed it into a mediaplayer to play? In specific, given a condition I need to start the video from a specific time. So probably I need to buffer the video stream from a specific time of the video.